# choosing the right mood for a sentence

Tags: grammar, verbs

What is the right mood for this sentence

> uh-huh. Well, I might watch it.

Is it **declarative or imperative, interrogative or none**?

Answer (score 3):

This would be a [declarative sentence](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/interrogative_sentence.htm). The person is simply declaring a piece of information:

> I might watch it

Interrogative is [asking a question.](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/interrogative_sentence.htm)

[Imperative](https://www.english-grammar-revolution.com/imperative-sentence.html) is giving a command.

Comment: Glad I could help.